# Doubts in verifying Extreme value of $xyz$ if $x+y+z=a$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

The book used lagrange multipliers to solve this. Here's the solution as per book.
$$ F = xyz + k(x+y+z-a)$$
Solved to get $$(x,y,z) = (\frac{a}{3},\frac{a}{3},\frac{a}{3})$$

Now,Verifying whether this point corresponds to maxima or minima but
$$F_{xx} = 0 $$.

As it can't be verified using second derivatives of $F$ , the book considers $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and verifies by second derivatives of $z$.

My questions are

-When can we assume $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, even when it is given in the problem as independent variable?

-We have to find extreme values of $F$ in the question. Then how can second derivatives test of $z$ verify the answer?

Comment: Are the variables assumed to be positive?

Comment: No. No other assumptions .

Comment: WA says neither minima nor maximia